# How to style Ionic 4 nested components

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, css-variables

I have some troubles with styling Ionic 4 components.
I have changed global variables: primary, secondary and background colors.

After changes, [ion-picker](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/picker) background also changed.

I have to add pickerOptions to ion-date:

```
<ion-datetime [pickerOptions]="picker"></ion-datetime>

picker = {
    cssClass: 'checkout-picker'
}
```

Than I tried to change background as [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/picker#css-custom-properties) said:

```
.checkout-picker {
    --background: white !important;
}
```

Nothing happened.

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
::ng-deep .checkout-picker {
    --background: white !important;
}
```